# Continuous integration for The cross-platform (Mainly Linux) development projects

Tags: linux, automation, continuous-integration, cross-platform

We are about to start a new Project in Linux Environment.

I would like to put the source code under Source Control System and automate the build process with a tool (Continuous integration System).

Can any one Suggest Please.

I am thinking of 
   - SVN for Source control.
   -TeamCity vs Jenkins Vs CruiseControl

NS

Comment: Could you add more info, like what kind of software stack you are using?

Answer (score 0):

How about Git, Gerrit and Jenkins. We are using it and it is a great Open Source combination.